# Install problems with homebrew's python

Tags: python, homebrew

Setting up a new mac here. I just installed python with `brew install python`, but when I try to install virtualenv with `sudo pip install virtualenv` it returns `sudo: pip: command not found`.

When I try `sudo easy_install pip` it returns the following response

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/bin/easy_install", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==33.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2697, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2370, in load
    return self.resolve()
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2376, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
    File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/setuptools/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named extern
```

I can't imagine what is happening, but with my old installation I had any of this problems. Any help woul be really helpful…

Comment: sudo easy_install really should work. Did you try brew? brew install python

Comment: brew installed pip renamed to pip2: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python.html

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Comment: If I remember well I solved it some time after I posted this question, and forgot to post the solution. I think it was with `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python`

Answer (score 0):

I update this question to post a possible solution:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python
```